# Parse the string using RegEx in notepad++

Tags: regex, string, macros, notepad++

I am trying to parse out some data using notepad++ macro. Here is the example of the data I have

```
  <abcdefghkdadajsdkdjg><hhDate>2019-12-31 <dklajdlajdkjasd>
```

I want `hhDate 2019-12-31` from the above data. I am very new to RegEx so I didn't try anything but I used notepad++ techniques to select and delete the unnecessary text but didn't work out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of the strings are on a new line because you have to capture the whole line to remove the 'junk' and leave the good stuff, find the start of the line (^), then find first bit you want to capture and wrap it in () then find the second bit and wrap it in (), then proceed on to the end of the line ($).

So in Notepad++ work to get all the strings on separate lines first if they are not already.  Then find/replace with 'regex' mode selected:

Find:

```
^.*?<.*?<(hhDate)>(\d+-\d+-\d+).*$
```

Replace:

```
$1 $2
```

https://regex101.com/r/BKha4m/1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `<` to be removed before hh ? Then try this short code.
Find what: `\s<.*?>`
Replace with: `nothing`

Otherwise use this `\s<.*?><|<.*>`

Uncheck  `match-case`